# Screen is flickering on iOS 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am created an app, after login have to download new database from web and when you logged 
in a custom UIAlertView appears if user press yes the download phase will be started. When 
the UIAlertView disappear and the UIAlertView's delegate called i start on the background 
thread a download. Now i am trying to modify a label which display the current percent and 
adding to the view a custom activity indicator. After that when the activity indicator 
changing the pictures or the label.text get a new string the screen start flickering, but 
only at the very first start (after install), if i force close the app and starting it 
again the flicker thing is not appearing, on previous version of iOS the app not flicker. I 
am calling from main thread when i modify the label. I tried remove label and activity 
indicator and after the alert view disappearing the app not flicker. I tried to remove 
alert view and start instantly the download and after that only the status bar started to 
flicker.

So my question: what should i do to solve the flicker bug?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the reason is because you are updating the UI on a background thread. You must not do this, you must use the main thread for this:

To run code on the main thread from the background thread, you can use GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your UI code here        
});
```

If this doesn't fix the error, it's probably a bug with your device.

Comment: Yes i am used that

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    loadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %%", percent];        
});


i also tried performSelectorOnMainThread to modify the label :/

Comment: @AdriánZukafuJuhász please post the code for detaching a new thread, and the methods that you are running in the background.

Comment: I used AFHTTPRequestOperation to download the file from the web so i add this operation to a bacground queue. and im using dispatch_get_main_queue() to modify the label